# Pin point performance issue in the past

Tags: performance, cpu-usage, memory-usage, rhel8, resources

I experienced a decrease of performance on my server and I was wondering if there is a possibility to lookback in time on a rhel8 machine. Where I can pinpoint which process claimed a lot of resources for a specific timestamp. For example between 15:00 and 17:00? Or to get a top 10 based on CPU, MEM resources or something like this.

If this is not possible, is there a way to log this in a sufficient way for the next time something like this occur?

Tnx again,

Cheers

Comment: AFAIK by default RHEL 8 and most, if not all, Linux distributions do not collect and record detailed metrics out of the box.  If you did not explicitly configure statistics collection beforehand, you won't have anything to fall back on.

Answer (score 1):

At least [`sar`](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/sar-system-statistics) from `sysstat` and [`atop`](https://haydenjames.io/atop-linux-server-performance-analysis/) can record performance metrics and display it on request at later time for analysis. Those are tools local to a server.

If you have more servers, it might be more convenient to run a generic dedicated monitoring system such as Nagios or Zabbix and make it collect enough performance data from your servers. You'll have a bonus of (almost) real-time alerts when something happens.